# Could someone check my work on this exercise

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups

I solved the following exercise, could someone please check my work?

Exercise:  Let

$$ A = 
\left ( \begin{array}{cccc} 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 
\end{array} \right ) $$

(1) Calculate $R_A(x,y,z,w)$.

(2) Describe a subgroup $H$ of $O(4)$ which is isomorphic to $S_4$ ($S_4$ is the group of permutations of a $4$-element set)

(3) Describe a subgroup $H$ of $O(n)$ which is isomorphic to $S_n$. What is $H \cap SO(n)$?

(4) Prove that every finite group is isomorphic to a subgroup of $O(n)$ for some integer $n$.

My work:

(1) $R_A (x,y,z,w) = (y, z, w, x)$

(2) The subgroup generated by all permutations of columns of $A$. It is clear that a permutation of the columns corresponds to a permutation of the elements in the vector $(x,y,z,w)$.

(3) Let $H$ be the group generated by all even permutations of the identity matrix. Since $H \subseteq SO(n)$ we have $H \cap SO(n) = H$.

(4) By Cayley's theorem every group is isomorphic to a group of permutations and by (3), this group is isomorphic to a subgroup of $O(n)$.

Comment: In (3), how do you know that $H \subseteq SO(n)$? In particular, suppose you start with the identity matrix and just perform one permutation, then the determinant is -1.

Comment: @Raskolnikov Thank you! You are right! I am thinking about how to fix this problem.

Comment: Another remark about (4), (3) if correct only shows that the group of permutations of a finite number of elements is isomorphic to a subgroup of $O(n)$. But I think Cayley's theorem says something more general.

Comment: @Raskolnikov My response to your first comment: Can I fix it by changing it to being the group generated by all *even* permutations of the identity matrix?

Comment: You mean $H \cap SO(n)$ is? Then yes, I think that's correct.

Comment: @Raskolnikov No, I meant $H \subseteq SO(n)$.

Comment: @Raskolnikov Cayley's theorem states that every group is isomorphic to a group of permutations. Is every group of permutations isomorphic to a group of even permutations?

Comment: No, Cayley's theorem states that every group is isomorphic to a **subgroup** of a group of permutations. Also note that Cayley's theorem also includes infinite groups.

Comment: @Raskolnikov But I feel that I should be able to use (1)-(3) to solve (4). For this I need that every finite group is isomorphic to the alternating group $A_n$ for some $n$. How can I do that?

Comment: @Raskolnikov What you write appears to be false, I just double checked both in my algebra book and Wikipedia: Cayley's theorem is stated as "Every group is isomorphic to a group of permutations".

Comment: Well, it's just a matter of wording, technically a subgroup of a group of permutations is still a group of permutations. But your statement that every finite group is isomorphic to the alternating group is obviously false. What do you do about the group $S_4$ how do you map odd permutations on even permutations?

Answer (score 1):

If you take all matrices that are formed by permuting the columns of an $n\times n$ identity matrix, you get a group of matrices isomorphic to $S_n$.

The isomorphism can be defined as follows

$$i:S_n\to H : \pi \mapsto i(\pi) \text{ with } (i(\pi))_{kl}=\delta_{k\pi(l)}$$

in which $\delta_{kl}$ is the Kronecker delta.

It is clear that it is bijective, and also note that given two permutations $\pi$ and $\rho$

$$(i(\pi)\cdot i(\rho))_{km} = \sum_{l=1}^n i(\pi)_{kl}\cdot i(\rho)_{lm} = \sum_{l=1}^n \delta_{k\pi(l)}\cdot \delta_{l\rho(m)}=\sum_{l=1}^n \delta_{\pi^{-1}(k)l}\cdot \delta_{l\rho(m)}=\delta_{\pi^{-1}(k)\rho(m)}=\delta_{k(\pi\circ\rho)(m)} = (i(\pi \circ \rho))_{km} \; .$$

Now $H\cap SO(n)$ implies that we add the additional constraint that the determinant be $1$. Odd permutations of the identity matrix will have determinant $-1$, so those are out. We are left with even permutations, but per our isomorphism, we know that those matrices will form a group isomorphic to $A_n$. Thus $H\cap SO(n) \cong A_n$.

Note that your answer is wrong because in (3) they explicitly define $H$ as being the subgroup of $O(n)$ isomorphic to $S_n$ and then ask about $H\cap SO(n)$. But then you go and redefine $H$ to be the group of all even permutations. You can't just do that.

By Cayley's theorem, every group is isomorphic to a group of permutations, but in particular every **finite** group is isomorphic to a **finite** group of permutations. And since we just showed that every finite group of permutations is isomorphic to a subgroup of $O(n)$, we obtain (4). Note the emphasis on finite is important and was lacking in your answer.